# How to add a quote to SQL statement

Tags: sql, psql

My goal is get a report of all the tables in public schema with basic count:

That's what I'm trying to do:

#### SQL:

```
SELECT 'select '||tablename||' as table_name, count(*) from '||tablename||' UNION ALL'
FROM pg_tables 
WHERE schemaname IN ('public') 
ORDER BY schemaname, tablename;
```

#### Sample Result:

```
select foo as table_name, count(*) from foo UNION ALL
select bar as table_name, count(*) from bar UNION ALL
select baz as table_name, count(*) from baz UNION ALL
```

I wanted to simply copy the above result (without last `union all` ) and paste it in the screen to get a report. that would look something like this:

```
     table_name      | count 
---------------------+-------
     foo             |  2436
     bar             |  1111
     baz             |  3333
(3 row)
```

But my problem is that I don't know how to place `'` around first reference to the table name, so the statement would look like this:

```
select 'foo' as table_name, count(*) from foo UNION ALL
select 'bar' as table_name, count(*) from bar UNION ALL
select 'baz' as table_name, count(*) from baz UNION ALL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put double apostrophe (`'`) as below

```
SELECT 'select '''||tablename||''' as table_name, count(*) from '||tablename||' UNION ALL'
FROM pg_tables 
WHERE schemaname IN ('public') 
ORDER BY schemaname, tablename;
```